# Python Loop Equivalent Excel Offset equivalent?

Tags: python, excel, loops

I am new to programming in Python and am trying to write a For/While loop that returns a value relative to another in a list based on the current value in the loop. The closest analog from excel I can think of is the OFFSET function, but my searches have failed to come up with an answer. Also, I believe VBA in excel allows you to use relative cells instead of absolute. Maybe this is a better analog.

As an example:

Suppose I have a simple list abc = [2,5,21,54,23,12,23] and I want to create a variable that is the current value in the loop divided by the prior value. So in this instance 5 would be divided by 2, 21 divided by 5, etc.

An example of the code would like something like:

```
for val in abc:
     xyz = val/val[-1]
     print(xyz)
```

I understand I would need to write an exception for the first iteration and the syntax is incorrect, but just trying to convey my message.

My search found that pandas has an ability to do this, but I was wanting to know if it is possible to do without pandas. Would appreciate any input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just loop by value since the value has no context of its position in the list. One way is to loop by index:

```py
# start from 1, not 0
for i in range(1, len(abc)):
    xyz = abc[i] / abc[i - 1]
    print(xyz)
```

Or, `zip` the list with its tail:

```py
for prev, cur in zip(abc, abc[1:]):
    xyz = cur / prev
    print(xyz)
```

For intuition on why this works:

```
            prev
             v
abc     -> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
abc[1:] -> 2 3 4 5 6 7
             ^
            cur
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) to do this:

```
abc = [2,5,21,54,23,12,23]

for index, val in enumerate(abc):
    print("VALUE: {}, PREVIOUS: {}, RESULT: {}".format(val, abc[index-1], val/abc[index-1]))
```

However, there is a gotcha here. Python can have negative indexes. Where it wraps around the the other side of the list. If you do the above, the first time through the loop you will see it do this:

```
VALUE: 2, PREVIOUS: 23, RESULT: 0.08695652173913043
```

So, to protect against that, you could do this:

```
abc = [2,5,21,54,23,12,23]

for index, val in enumerate(abc):
    if index > 0:
        print("VALUE: {}, PREVIOUS: {}, RESULT: {}".format(val, abc[index-1], val/abc[index-1]))
    else:
        print("First Value")
```

Resulting in this output:

```
First Value
VALUE: 5, PREVIOUS: 2, RESULT: 2.5
VALUE: 21, PREVIOUS: 5, RESULT: 4.2
VALUE: 54, PREVIOUS: 21, RESULT: 2.5714285714285716
VALUE: 23, PREVIOUS: 54, RESULT: 0.42592592592592593
VALUE: 12, PREVIOUS: 23, RESULT: 0.5217391304347826
VALUE: 23, PREVIOUS: 12, RESULT: 1.9166666666666667
```

Answer (score 0):

Pythonic style:

```
abc = [2,5,21,54,23,12,23]

gen = (abc[i + 1] / v for i, v in enumerate(abc) if i + 1 < len(abc))

for i in gen:
    print(i)
```

Result:

```
2.5
4.2
2.5714285714285716
0.42592592592592593
0.5217391304347826
1.9166666666666667
```